# Does Pssession work with TLS1.2 protocol?

Tags: powershell

I have set up my servers' WinRm to listen to Https request. I was able to use my computer to connect to my server through enter-pssession with using -UseSSL parameter and specifying my port. I followed mainly this [guide](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2012/02/24/how-to-force-winrm-to-listen-interfaces-over-https/) to set up the pssession with ssl. Everything was good and working.

I was asked to turn off TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 on the server and just use TLS1.2 protocol. After turning off TLS 1.0 and 1.1 protocol, I am unable to connect to my server with pssession now.

I am getting the error message:

> Enter-PSSession : Connecting to remote server xxxx.xxxx.com failed with the following error message : The SSL connection cannot be established. Verify that the service on the remote host is properly configured to listen for HTTPS requests. Consult the logs and documentation for the WS-Management service running on the destination, most commonly IIS or WinRM. If the destination is the WinRM service, run the following command on the destination to analyze and configure the WinRM service: "winrm quickconfig -transport:https". For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

I have googled a bunch and haven't found anything specific about turning off TLS protocols with pssesssion. Does anyone know if it is actually possible to connect with pssession with only TLS 1.2 protocol enabled on the server? It would be awesome if someone can even point me to the right direction to look for more information on this type of set up.

**Edit**

So we found a solution to the problem but we aren't 100% sure the details. For some reason, it works for Windows 10 and not for Windows 7. Hopefully this can help other people who had similar problem in the future.

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if, on the client before you start the session, you run `[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`?

Comment: @BaconBits I have tried that before and it gave me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/force-powershell-remoting-to-use-tls-1-2/), you can force the disabling of the other protocols

*Client.reg*

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001
"Enabled"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
```

Server.reg:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000000
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.0\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: I tried turning off Tls 1.0 and  1.1 on the client side to test if it works. It gave me a different error this time. The error I got was 
`The server certificate on the destination computer ( xxxx.xxxx.com:5986) has the following errors: encountered an internal error in the SSL Library.`
I haven't looked too much into the error but I don't think turning off the Tls 1.0 and 1.1 on the client side would be a good idea since I think there are still many applications that relies on those protocols. I also used IISCrypto the first place to turn off protocols on the Server.